# center image in PdfDocument

Tags: java, android

I have a PdfDocument A4 type.
I'd like to center an image vertically and horizontally on it. I tried this:

```
 PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new
                                    PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(595, 842, 1).create();
                            PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

                            Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
                            Rect rectangle = new Rect(0,0,500,500);

                            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapArray.get(i), null, rectangle, null);
                            document.finishPage(page);
```

But the image is not centered. Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

After looking for some solutions from various websites, i have managed to make an pdf generator app. Where i convert the whole view as it is in my pdf. It works for me. Hope that it may be a help to you.

```
private fun savePdf() {
    val printAttributes = PrintAttributes.Builder()
            .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4)
            .setResolution(Resolution("id", Context.PRINT_SERVICE, 400, 600))
            .setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR)
            .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
            .build()
    val pdfDocument = PrintedPdfDocument(this, printAttributes)
    val content = findViewById<View>(R.id.linearLayoutId)
    val pageInfo = PageInfo.Builder(content.width, content.height, 1).create()
    val page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo)
    content.draw(page.canvas)
    pdfDocument.finishPage(page)
    val file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/hello9.pdf")
    try {
        pdfDocument.writeTo(FileOutputStream(file))
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    pdfDocument.close()
}
```

Comment: This seems to be incomplete, can your provide the full code snippet. Also, is there any way to add image in full resolution to pdf with scaling?

Answer (score 1):

I was not working on a solution to center an image in a pdf. My view is actually a table layout but doing this is what allowed me to center the canvas inside the generated PDF. Centering your image inside the pdf should be the same.

```
Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
canvas.translate(dx, dy);
```

Where dx and dy are float values that will move your canvas along the x and y axes.

I then added the code below, in my case, to complete what I needed to do.

```
view.draw(canvas);
document.finishPage(page);
```

Answer (score 1):

to place objects centrally you take width of page and object and Subract/2

Before

```
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new
                                    PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(595, 842, 1).create();
                            PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

                            Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
                            Rect rectangle = new Rect(0,0,500,500);

                            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapArray.get(i), null, rectangle, null);
                            document.finishPage(page);
```

every day maths `new Rect ( (595-500)/2, (842-500)/2, 500, 500 )`
so 95/2 and 342/2

After

```
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new
                                    PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(595, 842, 1).create();
                            PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

                            Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
                            Rect rectangle = new Rect(47.5,171,500,500);

                            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapArray.get(i), null, rectangle, null);
                            document.finishPage(page);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

```
// Calculate the size of the page
int pageWidth = 595;
int pageHeight = 842;

// Get the size of the bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = bitmapArray.get(i);
int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

// Calculate the scale factor to fit the bitmap onto the page
float scaleFactor = Math.min((float)pageWidth / bitmapWidth, (float)pageHeight / bitmapHeight);

// Calculate the new bitmap dimensions and position to center it on the page
int scaledBitmapWidth = (int)(bitmapWidth * scaleFactor);
int scaledBitmapHeight = (int)(bitmapHeight * scaleFactor);
int left = (pageWidth - scaledBitmapWidth) / 2;
int top = (pageHeight - scaledBitmapHeight) / 2;
int right = left + scaledBitmapWidth;
int bottom = top + scaledBitmapHeight;
Rect rectangle = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);

// Draw the scaled bitmap on the canvas at the calculated position
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, scaledBitmapWidth, scaledBitmapHeight, true);
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(pageWidth, pageHeight, 1).create();
PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBitmap, null, rectangle, null);
document.finishPage(page);
```